# Define a global variable in a php class

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that has an iterative function like below:

```
<?php

class Helper
{


    public static function get_children($mid)
    {

        ...
        $permission = getPermissionFromDB($mid);
        if ($permission)
            $mid = get_children($mid);
    }

}
```

This function in each iteration checks for the `id` permission from a db. This simply means that I query the db thousand times that make the loading very slow. What I am thinking is that I need to get all id permissions (for a specific user) from the db beforehand and store the permission ids in an array (like `$permissed_ids`). Then use the array for checking the permissions like below:

```
   <?php

class Helper
{


    public static function get_children($mid)
    {

        ...
        $permission = in_array($mid,$permissed_ids);
        if ($permission)
            $mid = get_children($mid);
    }

}
```

Having said that, I do not know what is the best way of putting `$permissed_ids` outside the iterative function that is secure, accessible in the class and specific to the user.

Comment: Do you want this data to persist across multiple calls to the object or multiple instantiations of the class?

Comment: it is better to do that in your SQL query only one query will do all of this stuff instead of thousands of iterations as you mention

Comment: Something like `private static $permissed_ids;`.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks. It is more complicated than this example. I need to go for the iterative function

Comment: Then you might consider putting the array in SESSION

Comment: @NigelRen I tried this. I cannot initialise the value in the private call with a function (like `private static $permised_ids =query($user_id))`

Comment: Why not?  I would normally check if the value is null and only then call a method to initialise the data.

Comment: @NigelRen I really do not know, it says: expression is not allowed as field default value

Answer (score 0):

A static method may not be the most practical tool when the task is not straightforward. In any case, I understand `$permissed_ids` are application wide, so they can be shared among instances, and they're also costly to obtain, so they should be shared among instances. They also depend on `$mid` thus you need a key => value structure to store them. That basically leaves a static variable as most obvious simple solution (either a static class property or a static method variable):

```
class Foo
{
    private static $a = 'a';
    
    public static function bar()
    {
        static $b = 'b';
        var_dump(self::$a, $b);
    }
}

Foo::bar();
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/41bZe))

This is just a quick example to illustrate the syntax, you can of course set the values dynamically and, as said, you need a structure such as an associative array.

A more elaborate example ([online](https://tio.run/##lZJBi8IwEIXv@RWzILSFsqDHuosnlz0I9uRFpMSa0oHaZJNUEPG314nVUqRl65zCyzdvkpeoXNX110LlirG04MbAj5TswoBKaTxxK8BYbjGFiRL6iMagLA18w3Y3Zw1W7QvaflBZVaaWEOAm1pJa7NmfHPEQ3NnG2BVm4H@Qm7C@EUUWRV37revYBUGHdzUE0mmqEv/wcJ8En@AlimYnXghWVyKYty7XdiXSXILDQ/Con9Ah9xDi3zhZrleNzfWfW2@4Rr4vRO@th6PsyWVEIqOyOHH9ZhQjQqAY6KdEUeeZp@T@qs16NMc9xTatTnOrzXo0x9X1DQ)):

```
class Foo
{
    private static $permissions = [];

    public static function asProperty($mid)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$permissions[$mid])) {
            self::$permissions[$mid] = uniqid($mid . '_prop_', true);
        }
        echo $mid, ' = ', self::$permissions[$mid], PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function asVariable($mid)
    {
        static $permissions = [];
        if (!isset($permissions[$mid])) {
            $permissions[$mid] = uniqid($mid . '_var_', true);
        }
        echo $mid, ' = ', $permissions[$mid], PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The main difference between both is that class properties can be shared between methods (or accessed from other classes if visibility allows it) and method variables cannot.

Comment: Thanks but my 'a' is the return of a function. I replaced your 'a' with rand(1,2) and it does not work :(

Comment: @Rose I've added a hopefully more insightful snippet

Comment: Thanks. Cannot it be as simple as: ` private static $GLOBALS;

    static function init()
    {
        self::$GLOBALS = function(...);
    }`

Comment: `$GLOBALS` is easier than that: it's a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) so it's automatically available inside your class method, you don't need to do anything else. The point is that having a class suggests your application design is object-oriented, thus I can't see how `$GLOBALS` fits in there.